# Exit status of ping command

Tags: unix

My Perl script gets stuck with an `exit status` when trying to use the `ping` command.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 33):

According to [this](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm) website:

> If ping does **not receive any reply** packets at all it will exit with **code 1**. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with code 1. On **other error it exits with code 2**. **Otherwise** it exits with **code 0**. This makes it possible to use the exit code to see if a host is alive or not.

To list the results:

- Success: code 0
- No reply: code 1
- Other errors: code 2

Note that the page I link to says "Linux/Unix ping command", but other systems, or perhaps even variants of Linux and Unix, might vary this value.

If possible, I would test on the system in question to make sure you have the right ones.

Answer (score 16):

It's worth doing some testing on this on your OS. e.g on OSX

**Resolvable host which is up**

```
ping -c 1 google.com ;  echo $?
```

Replies:

```
PING google.com (173.194.38.14): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.38.14: icmp_seq=0 ttl=51 time=16.878 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 16.878/16.878/16.878/0.000 ms
```

Returns

```
0
```

**Resolvable host which is down/does not respond to ping**

```
ping -c 1 localhost  ;  echo $?
```

Replies:

```
PING stuart-woodward.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes

--- stuart-woodward.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Returns:

```
2
```

**Non Resolvable host**

```
ping -c 1 sdhjfjsd  ;  echo $?
```

Replies:

```
ping: cannot resolve sdhjfjsd: Unknown host
```

Returns:

```
68
```

Comment: Bad param... :/

Answer (score 13):

> The ping utility returns an exit
>   status of zero if at least one
>   response was heard from the specified
>   host; a status of two if the
>   transmission was successful but no
>   responses were received; or another
>   value (from ) if an error
>   occurred.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ping

The actual return values may depend on your system.

Comment: my ping man page doesn't have an exit status section (mint 17)

Answer (score 4):

You should also take into account that if the ping for example receives a 'network unreachable' icmp reply, it will be counted as reply an thus returns success status 0 (tested with cygwin ping on windows). So not really useful for testing if a host is alive and IMO a bug.

Here's an example from Git Bash showing an exit value of `0`, despite encountering an obvious error:

```
$ ping -n 1 172.27.27.48 ; echo $?

Pinging 172.27.27.48 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.31.100.2: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 172.27.27.48:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
0
```

Answer (score 2):

Successful connection will always return **code 0**, whilst failed connections will always return **code 1 and above**.

To test this out, try this snippet

```
#!/bin/bash
light_red='\e[1;91m%s\e[0m\n'                     
light_green='\e[1;92m%s\e[0m\n'                   
ping -c 4 -q google.comz                          
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then                           
  printf "$light_green" "[ CONNECTION AVAILABLE ]"
else                                              
  printf "$light_red" "[ HOST DISCONNECTED ]"     
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `man ping` from the command line. The return values are listed near the bottom.

Comment: No, they are not. For example GNU ping seems to return 255 if you did not give it enough time to send all packets. This seems to be documented nowhere.