# Logging ping successes and failures in linux

Tags: python, linux, shell, ping

Here's a short version of my situation. My current ISP is not working properly, and as a result, I'd like to log ping successes and failures as proof it isn't working. I'll be on Linux, but Windows would be fine too. I've been reading, and as far as I can tell, a shell script or Python code would work best.

So, being more detailed: I'd like to do a single ping at a website every 5 seconds. If there is a successful ping, it should output the normal results of the ping to a file. Ping failures however have a long timeout, so I'd like to make the program so that if the ping hasn't succeeded in 4 seconds or so, it stops the ping attempt, but still outputs the full ping data with a "1 packet transmitted, 0 received" etc, like it would have if it had run out of time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
while true
do
    ping -c1 -w4 www.example.com >> log.txt
    sleep 5
done
```

Unfortunately, there are 2 problems. First, the "-w4" isn't making it time out after 4 seconds like I thought it would. And second, the "sleep" adds on to the time already spent. So, if the ping takes 3 seconds, the loop will take 8 seconds. Since I will be writing another program that will count the successes, failures, and output the down time percent, having loops take a lot of extra time on a failure isn't acceptable.

So, given what I need, what's the best way to go about this? Can what I have be improved to meed the needs? Thank you for any help!

PS: I know almost nothing about writing shell scripts, (though I'm competent with a terminal), and I know even less about Python (though I know C++). Apologies in advance!

Comment: I think you want `-t` instead of `-w`. On my system, `-w` doesn't exist. `-W` refers to a wait time for individual packets, while `-t` appears to be the ‘timeout’ setting you want.

Comment: I think the value of `$?` after you run `ping` will tell you if it succeeded or not. It appears that an exit code of `2` [means that there was an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921398/exit-status-of-the-ping-command).

Comment: @WaleedKhan: Your system probably has a BSD userland, like OS X, not a GNU one, like linux.

Comment: I gave -t a try, but it just gives me an error that "time to live" has exceeded, even when a normal ping works. On my system, the man pages say that -w specifies a success deadline, which sounded right.

Comment: @Leonhart231: In [GNU/Linux `ping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping), `-t` is "ttl", and `-w` is "deadline". In [BSD `ping`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ping.8.html), `-t` is "timeout" and `-w` doesn't exist. Using manpages (or other users' experience) from the wrong system isn't going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make the whole loop take no more than 5 seconds, you have to know how long ping took, then subtract that from 5, and sleep the difference.

You can do this from bash either by recording the time before and after ping and subtracting, or by using the `time -p` command to run the `ping` (the second column of the first non-blank line will be wall-clock time as a float, like `0.01`).

But I think this will be easier from Python:

```
import datetime
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open('log.txt', 'a+b') as logfile:
        subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', '-w4', 'www.example.com'], stdout=logfile)
    delta = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    time.sleep(delta.total_seconds())
```

---

Of course this won't work if `ping` doesn't finish in at most 5 seconds, because you can't sleep for negative time. You *could* solve that by using an explicit `Popen` and calling `wait(5)` on it, then killing if it fails…

But it's a lot simpler to just always give it 5 seconds, whether it needs that much or not:

```
while True:
    with open('log.txt', 'a+b') as logfile:
        ping = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c1', '-w4', 'www.example.com'],
                                stdout=logfile)
        time.sleep(5)
        # Not strictly necessary, but it avoids signaling for no reason
        if ping.poll() is None:
            ping.kill()
        ping.wait()
```

Comment: Excellent. It's working well, but I'll probably mess with it some more, and see if I can't learn some Python while I'm at it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put ping on the background instead and use another subprocess to wait and kill it:

```
while true
do
    ping -c1 www.example.com >> log.txt &
    p=$!
    ( sleep 4s; kill -s SIGABRT "$p"; ) &>/dev/null &
    wait "$p"
    sleep 5
done
```

Adjust the timeout if needed.

Comment: While this seems to be timing out after 5 seconds, instead of printing a failure to the log file, it's just dumping core.

Comment: @Leonhart231 Maybe you shouldn't use SIGABRT. Try a normal signal like SIGTERM or perhaps SIGHUP.

Comment: On some glibc systems, `man signal` shows a list of default signal handlers, so you can just pick one that does a `terminate process` instead of a `create core image`. On other glibc systems, that list is somewhere else, and I can't remember where… But anyway, `SIGABRT` defaults to dumping core, and `SIGTERM` does not, and that should be true on any POSIX-ish system.