# How to make script in bash aware that a server is still busy installing/configuring and wait for reboot?

Tags: bash, shell, automation

## The issue / dilemma

I am currently busy creating a script to kickstart servers (with CentOS 6.x and CentOS 7.x) remotely. So far the script is working, but hangs on one minor thing. Well actually it does not hang, but it does not give detailed information about what is happening. In other words, I am not getting the correct information back in bash about the job being finished correctly.

I have tried various things, however it's hanging with the following message (which is being repeated endlessly):

```
servername is still installing and configuring packages...
PING 100.125.150.175 (100.125.150.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.152 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.157 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.157 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.143 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.182 ms

--- 100.125.150.175 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 120025ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.143/0.158/0.182/0.015 ms

servername is still installing and configuring packages...
PING 100.125.150.175 (100.125.150.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.153 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 100.125.150.175: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.142 ms

etc....
```

So for some reason it does not contine to the next line of code or does the next action. Since it's only feedback to me (or another user), it's not a majorissue. But it would be nice to get this functional and providing (detailed) information back about the current progress or what the script/server is actually doing at the moment. This is not the case for the above (last) piece of code unfortunately.

This is the current code snippet I have (yes, it's a mess):

```
while true;
do
  #ping -c3 -i3 $HWNODEIP  > /dev/null
  #ping -c5 -i30 $HWNODEIP > /dev/null
  ping -c5 -i30 $HWNODEIP
  if [ $? -eq 1 ] || [ $? -eq 2 ] || [ $? -eq 68 ]
  then
    echo -e " "
    echo -e "Kickstart part II also done. $HOSTNAME will be rebooted one more time."
    sleep 5
    ######return 0
    
        echo -e " "
        printf "%s" "Waiting for $HOSTNAME to come back online: "
        while ! ping -c 1 -n -w 30 $HWNODEIP &> /dev/null
            do
                printf "%c" "."
                #sleep 10
            done
            
        echo -e " "
        echo -e "Reboot is done and $HOSTNAME is back online. Performing final check. Please wait..."
        sleep 10
        echo -e " "
        sudo /usr/local/collectHWdata.pl $HWNODEIP
        ssh root@$HWNODEIP "while ! test -e /root/kickstart-DONE; do sleep 3; done; echo KICKSTART IS DONE\!"
        echo -e " "
    exit        
    
  else
    echo -e " "
    echo -e "$HOSTNAME is still installing and configuring packages..."
  fi
done
```

*Sidenote: I removed  > /dev/null #5 for debugging (not that it helped)*

I am guessing I am using things incorrectly and I am by no means a experienced scripter; I can only do minor stuff, but ofcourse I am doing my best. I have been fooling around with this since last week and still no result on this part.

## What am I trying to achieve?

The server is rebooted after the selected CentOS version, creating partitions and setting up the network. This all works. The above snippet is after that reboot. Now it will install packages I selected, configure various things (like Nagios) and install/compile certain PERL modules. And a few other minor things.

This is done correctly in the background. I wanted to make the script (the above piece of code) that the server is still busy with installing things and such. Since I lack the knowledge to do that, I decided for a different approach; check if the server is online (in other words that it's still installing). As long as the server is online, it's still installing/configuring things obviously. After that is done, the server will reboot once more to perform the final 2 commands (as seen in my snippet). However (here is the problem) it never does those commands, though the kickstart is completely done.

So I am guessing I am doing something wrong and even might messed up things (or got confused by doing so). Maybe someone has an idea, solution or a completely different approach to tackle and fix this problem (or at least I hope so).

Other things I have tried so far? Well I tried a various of ping commands and I also tried nc (netcat) but also without a good result. I every single time hit a brick wall with the last 2 commands and it keeps pinging instead of showing that the kickstart was done... I think I have spend several hours (since last week) on this already without getting anywhere.

So I am hoping someone can take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong and maybe there is a better approach (other than pinging a server) to see if it's still busy. Maybe a (remote) check on yum, perl or a service, so that the script knows it's still busy.

*Sorry for the long post, but I know when I provide as much information as possible including code examples and results, this is more "appreciated". So I am hoping I provided adequate information. If not, let me know. I will try to add as much information as I can. As always I am always willing to learn or change my approach.*

Thank you already for reading my post!

Comment: IMHO why don't you write scripts or integrate scripts in systemctl scripts, it does take care of shutting down the services gracefully.

Comment: Add string 'reboot' in your kickstart file. After string 'install'.

Comment: Reboot is not the issue, as it is done by the kickstart script on the remote server itself.

Comment: Does the kickstart script actually reboot the server ? Is this a VPS server ? My guess would be either 1) the server never actually reboots or 2) there's something else that responds. I can't provide exact explanation, but I've seen at least one case where a person had VPS server with no-ip set there or something, and despite their server being down, VPS provider's  ip address still responded. Do you have ssh on the servers ? You could also have ssh session opened. When server actually reboots, that session would be closed.  These are just suggestions, though, can't give a definite solution.

Comment: `[ $? -eq 68 ]` is probably unnecessary. `$HWNODEIP` is just ip address, and exit code 68 is for domain name not being resolved, which doesn't apply to IP addresses. In fact, we probably could just do `if ! ping -c5 -i30 $HWNODEIP` there. Another thing to consider maybe is `-i` interval. You send 5 packets, waiting 30 seconds between each packet. So thats's 5*30, 150 seconds, which is a bit more than 2 minutes. A server could reboot just fine within 2 minutes, especially if there's SSD in use. So try lowering the total time it would take this command

Comment: Hi Sergiy! I appreciate your time and answer(s). The script which is being run on the remote (kickstart) server has a command to "reboot" on the end. My script (or what I am trying to do) is to check if the server is still busy installing and compiling Perl modules. Depending on the server this can take from 10 - 20 minutes. That's why I am pinging. So the script provides feedback that the server is still online and busy. When the server is done, it will reboot and the script should notice that as well (that's why I am using the script as posted). When the server is back it should proceed...

Comment: But that does not happen, as mentioned in the script. I have no clue why. Maybe I should approach this issue differently. I am just trying to make my script wait, until the remote kickstarted server is done installing/compiling and the reboot is done in order to proceed with the final commands. Sounds silly/stupid probably?

I have been busy with this to get working since last week and I cannot get it working. Ofcourse I could skip pinging and make the script wait simply one hour, but that would waste time.

Comment: Anyways (sorry bit early here) I will try what you recommended to see if that works.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if any of that helps. Don't forget to add @ before the name, otherwise users don't get notified of new messages

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy thank you for reminding me about the @. Okay so i followed your advice and tried it (I also lowered the count and interval). And... It seems to work now. :-) At least it's not hanging. Maybe there is a better (nicer) solution other than keep posting "is still installing and configuring packages...", but for now this works. Would be nicer if you could get some feedback on what the server is doing now. But then again. Wishful thinking. ;-) At least this works for me. Thank you again!! Maybe create an answer, so i can select it as best answer?

Comment: @Joanne Answer posted. Accepting is not required - it's question asker's personal choice, so only accept if the answer is still helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments under the question:

- The server may already be rebooted by the time `ping -c5 -i30 $HWNODEIP` finishes. The command sends 5 packets (`-c` flag), waiting 30 seconds between each packet (`-i interval` flag). So thats's 5*30 = 150 seconds, which is a bit more than 2 minutes. A server could reboot just fine within 2 minutes, especially if there's SSD in use. So try lowering the total time it would take this command to complete.
- `[ $? -eq 68 ]` is probably unnecessary. `$HWNODEIP` is just ip address, and [exit code 68 is for domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153862/3701431) not being resolved, which doesn't apply to IP addresses.
- The `if` statement could be simplified to

  ```
  if ! ping -c5 -i30 "$HWNODEIP"
  ```

These are minor suggestions,probably not bulletproof. As confirmed by OP in the comments, lowering interval helps. There's other small improvements that could be done (like quoting variables), but that's outside the scope of the question, so I'll leave it for now.

Comment: Thank you! :-)
It really works. Apparently the boot was faster than the checks. Sometimes the solution is really easy.