# Odd behavior with threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm developping a little script in PYTHON3 for pinging IPs ranges with multiples threads.
I only ping my localhost for now.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import _thread
import os

# Define a function for the thread
def pingBox( threadName, value):
    range='127.0.0.'
    host=''+str(range)+str(value)
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 "+host +"2>&1 >/dev/null") #to don't show the output
    print('response for pinging %s is %s' %(threadName, response))
    if response == 0:
        print ('%s : is up' %host)
    else:
        print ('%s : is down' %host)
# Create one thread by ping
try:
   for x in range (1,100):
    _thread.start_new_thread( pingBox, ("Thread-"+str(x), x) )
except Exception as e: print(e)

while 1:
   pass
```

With this code, I get some strange answer, like for instance :

> response for pinging Thread-89 is 512

Why 512? I don't understand why response has this value.

PS: I know that for now, this code is a completely massacre regarding the threading aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few mistakes I found:

- Use `threading` library in python3. Read more about threading interfaces [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html).
- The `while` loop at end makes no sense, please remove that.

Replacing with `_thread` with `threading` interfaces, your program will now look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
import os

# Define a function for the thread
def pingBox( threadName, value):
    range='127.0.0.'
    host=''+str(range)+str(value)
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 "+host +"2>&1 >/dev/null") #to don't show the output
    print('response for pinging %s is %s' %(threadName, response))
    if response == 0:
        print ('%s : is up' %host)
    else:
        print ('%s : is down' %host)
# Create one thread by ping
try:
   tlist = []
   for x in range (1,100):
      tlist.append(
          threading.Thread(
              target=pingBox,
              kwargs={
                  "threadName": "Thread:{0}".format(x),
                  "value":x
              }
      ))

   for t in tlist:
      t.start()

   for t in tlist:
      t.join()
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: Does it show `512` ? Ping should return either 0,1,2, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/921441/6400614