# Check ping results with subprocess

Tags: python

I am working on a small IP address scanner, and am running into issues with the results from `.poll()`. I get a return from what I'm assuming is the router, so I get a 0 either way. I would've commented on a different post but I don't have the rep. So how can I check these results in a way that takes this into account?

```
import subprocess
from netaddr import *
import os
hosts = []
for ip in IPNetwork('192.168.14.157/22'):
    hosts.append(ip)
    p = subprocess.Popen('ping ' + str(ip))
    p.wait()
    print(p.poll())
```

idle output looks pretty much like:

```
0
1
0
0
3221225786 <When I exit a prompt before stopping the program
```

and cmd outputs are:

```
Pinging 192.168.12.5 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.14.157: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.14.157: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.14.157: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.14.157: Destination host unreachable.

and 

Pinging 192.168.12.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.12.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.12.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.12.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.12.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
```

Comment: What is your goal with this code ? What is expected output, what is the actual output ?

Comment: Yes, but not perfect : what is your problem ?

Comment: @Programmer I am eventually going to be printing out a list of usable addresses, but right now I am looking for a reliable way of checking ping results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store output of subprocess.Popen call in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/921441/14909980) may be helpful, too